# Converting Int array of single digits to Int of multiple digits

Tags: c#, arrays, string, int

I have made an array that take an input say "12345" and splits it down into the following

0 - 1
1 - 2
2 - 3
3 - 4
4 - 5

I then shuffle these numbers up a little to get

0 - 5
1 - 2
2 - 3
3 - 4
4 - 1

Once this is done i want to return the take this array and create an int of the new order , so the output i want is "52341"

I though i had solved this up I an the following error when I run my code 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

So here is my code and can anyone help?

C#

```
string result = number[i].ToString();
var intList = result.Select(digit => Int64.Parse(digit.ToString()));
Int64[] Circle = intList.ToArray();

int order = Circle.Length;
int check = 0;
while (check < order)
{
    numholder = Circle[0];
    Array.Copy(Circle, 1, Circle, 0, Circle.Length - 1);

    Circle[order - 1] = numholder;
    //string p = Circle.ToString();
    //string p = Circle.ToString();
    Int64 h = Int64.Parse(Circle.ToString());
```

Comment: `Circle.ToString()` will give you  _System.Int64[]_, which definitely cannot be parsed to an Int64...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
Int64 h = Int64.Parse(Circle.ToString());
```

This is because `Circle.ToString()` returns `Int64[]`, and this isn't the correct `Int64`

I think you should use this line with [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx):

```
Int64 h = Int64.Parse(String.Join("", Circle));
```

Comment: Thanks for the VM that line got my code working again. - also ty for everyone else for helping.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing to do would be to skip the string altogether, and use the definition of a multi-digit number from the elementary school:

```
var res = 0L;
var mul = 1L;
foreach (var digit in Circle) {
    res += mul*digit;
    mul *= 10;
}
```

You could also create a string from your digits and parse it, but that is less efficient:

```
var numStr = string.Join("", Circle.Select(digit => digit.ToString()));
var num = long.Parse(numStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing code but couldn't you do a Join on the data?

```
string newresult = order.Join("");
```

Not got VS on here so can't check code but something like that should work

Comment: I have never used the .join method before and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] singleDigitArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 5, 8};
int num = 0;
for (int i = singleDigitArray.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    num += ((int)Math.Pow(10, singleDigitArray.Length-i-1)) * singleDigitArray[i];
}
```